# I cannot make camunda map element as a child element of Input parameter.Could not understand why?

Tags: java, bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler

Code Spinnet :

```
                CamundaInputParameter camundaInputParameter2=createElement(camundaInputOutput, CamundaInputParameter.class);
            camundaInputParameter2.setCamundaName("headers");

            CamundaMap camundamap = createElement(camundaInputParameter2, CamundaMap.class);
            CamundaEntry camundaentry = createElement(camundamap, CamundaEntry.class);
            camundaentry.setCamundaKey("Accept");
            camundaentry.setTextContent("application/json");
```

JSON Response :

{
  "timestamp": 1518705529135,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.camunda.bpm.model.xml.ModelException",
  "message": "New child is not a valid child element type: map; valid types are: []",
  "path": "/camunda/updateWorkflow/"

Comment: Hi Albin, 

just to make sure I understand context properly, are you trying to construct BPMN diagram using Model API in runtime? If that's so, would you mind doing one sample process definition diagram manualy using modeler and sharing it here in order for me to better understand what you are modeling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was facing the same issue. According to the Camunda docs: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/reference/bpmn20/custom-extensions/extension-elements/#inputparameter
the map element is in the list of child elements of inputParameter, so it should work but it doesn't.
A workaround would be:

```
    CamundaInputParameter headers = model.newInstance(CamundaInputParameter.class);
    headers.setCamundaName("headers");

    CamundaMap map = model.newInstance(CamundaMap.class);
    CamundaEntry entry = model.newInstance(CamundaEntry.class);
    entry.setCamundaKey("Content-Type");
    entry.setTextContent("application/json");
    map.addChildElement(entry);
    //headers.addChildElement(map); does not work
    headers.getDomElement().appendChild(map.getDomElement()); // works
```